# Laravel Mix / Webpack: When I call "npm run prod" it doesn't minify .scripts but does minify .js

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

Here's my `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.setPublicPath('public');

mix.sass('resources/sass/frontend/app.scss', 'css/frontend.css')
    .sass('resources/sass/backend/app.scss', 'css/backend.css')
    .js('resources/js/frontend/app.js', 'js/frontend.js')
    .js([
        'resources/js/backend/before.js',
        'resources/js/backend/app.js',
        'resources/js/backend/after.js',
    ], 'js/backend.js')
    .scripts([
        './node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.js',
    ], 'public/js/clipboard.js')
    .extract([
        'jquery',
        'bootstrap',
        'popper.js/dist/umd/popper',
        'axios',
        'sweetalert2',
        'lodash',
        '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core',
        '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons',
        '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction() || process.env.npm_lifecycle_event !== 'hot') {
    mix.version();
}
```

When I call `npm run prod` all files under `.js` (`frontend.js`, `backend.js`) are displayed minified on blade but `clipboard.js` is not.

Why?

Comment: Why not just use the minified version from the distribution? ```./node_modules/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js```

Comment: According to this thread (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1295) one option might be to nuke your node_modules folder and then reinstall your dependencies.

Comment: Hey @CUGreen, what if a lib does not come with minified version?

Comment: Use ```js``` instead of ```scripts```